# Are feature axes non-orthogonal to one another if their correlations are non-zero?

Tags: correlation, pca

I'm using PCA in R for dimensionality reduction and the correlations between principal components are zero as they are orthogonal to one another. This made me wonder whether features that have  non-zero  correlation coefficients are non-orthogonal? Does this not always hold true that axes representing features are orthogonal to one another?

Comment: No, it is not true that *axes representing features are orthogonal to one another*! From where did you get that idea?